# FacebookShare causing compiler error after update

Tags: swift, facebook, cocoapods

I just ran `pod update` for my app, and now it won't compile, giving these issues from `LinkShareContent.swift` in `FacebookShare`.

```
Cannot assign to property: 'contentDescription' is a get-only property
Cannot assign to property: 'contentTitle' is a get-only property
Cannot assign to property: 'imageURL' is a get-only property
```

These were the Facebook-related lines in my pod update:

```
Installing FBSDKCoreKit 4.23.0 (was 4.22.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit 4.23.0 (was 4.22.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit 4.23.0 (was 4.22.0)
Using FacebookCore (0.2.0)
Using FacebookLogin (0.2.0)
Using FacebookShare (0.2.0)
```

Does anyone know about this problem? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: upload  the piece of code for share

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Regarding docs of `FBSDKShareLinkContent` these properties have been deprecated:

> @deprecated `contentDescription` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9.
>        For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations.
>
> @deprecated `contentTitle` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9.
>        For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations
>
> @deprecated `imageURL` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9.
>        For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations

You should probably use `quote` and `contentURL` instead of them.

**As a temporary solution, you can unblock the file `LinkShareContent.swift` and directly remove above lines until Facebook releases any update.**

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: This fixed the same my problem too

Comment: Same issue here. Can you elaborate on what steps need to be taken? Since this code is inside a Library `RCTFBSDK` library, can I edit them without fear of it being overwritten? Could I just comment out the entire `FBSDKShareLinkContent` code block? I don't even use this functionality in my project anyhow.

Comment: I would recommend to mix this answer with @Brigadier answer, create a fork of the sdk and comment these properties, then just point to your repo, if you change these directly at the project podlock file brokes.

Answer (score 24):

I do not think referencing Github user 1amageek's repo with

```
pod 'FacebookShare', :git => 'https://github.com/1amageek/facebook-sdk-swift'
```

is a good idea, 1amageek could be the most awesome developer in the world and still delete his/her fork of the Facebook Swift SDKs

Until fixed you should change your Podfile to

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.2'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '~> 0.2'
pod 'FacebookShare', '~> 0.2'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.22.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.22.1'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.22.1'
```

And run `pod update` again.

Note that this code is not adding "duplicate" pods (older FBSDK[Core etc] + newer Facebook[Core etc]), the code is just being completely explicit about the Pods you are installing. If you were to list only pods `FacebookCore`, `FacebookLogin`, and `FacebookShare`, the FBSDKs will be installed by Cocoapods as dependencies anyways.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/157

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me. Can I ask you what you meant by "if you were to just have FacebookCore, FacebookLogin, and FacebookShare in your Podfile the FBSDKs will be installed"?

Comment: @cheznead I updated that part of my answer to try it make more sense, let me know if you are still not clear

Answer (score 21):

Replace your Podfile content with this:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare', :git => 'https://github.com/1amageek/facebook-sdk-swift'
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what that does?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman it lets you compile your project without those errors you posted. It's a Facebook SDK written in Swift (currently in Beta).

Comment: Is this third party repo honor? Can we trust it?

Comment: @RobertYiJiang Yes it is "third party" and no I do not think it should be relied upon